# Faster RCNN - Pyramid of Filters vs Pyramid of Anchors (Reference Boxes)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, filter

I'm reading faster RCNN [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf) now and trying to understand what is the difference between *Pyramid of Filters* and *Pyramid of Anchors* methods from the scale point of view. I mean if I use only one aspect ratio (1:1) with *Pyramid of Anchors* how it will be different from *Pyramid of Filters*?

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265875/anchoring-faster-rcnn) a bit related question.